# I'm getting no results while trying to make a reaction bot with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code is:

```
@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):

    message_id = payload.message_id
    if message_id == 768549092674502666:
        if payload.emoji.name == 'white_check_mark':
            role = '<:Member:765291826151555104>'
            await member.add_role(role)
```

and i'm getting no results from the debugger or except when the bot adds a reaction or logs on which are other code completely inaccosiated with this part of the code.

Comment: Who is `member`?

Comment: Member is the adder of the reaction, or so the docs say

Comment: but if you're talking about the role, its just my role in my server that i've made

Comment: Ok thanks. I was talking about the variable `member` not the role. Is it defined earlier in your code?

Comment: no, none other place mentions it in my code, do i have to do payload.member or something?

Answer (score 1):

In the new version of discord.py(1.5.x), there're some updates about `Intents`. Intents are like permissions and for using some of the events or getting members, channels etc. you need to define it before you define the `client = discord.Bot(prefix='')`.

Then, you need to define the `member` to add role. You can simply do `member = payload.member`.

And also you need to get role with `discord.utils.get()`. You can't define a role with string.

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.message_id == 768549092674502666 and payload.emoji.name == 'white_check_mark':
        guild = client.get_guild(guild id)
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="role's name")
        await payload.member.add_roles(role)
```

If you want to get more information about Intents, you can check the [API References](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents)

Comment: now it says:
`module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'` am i supposed to fill in the blank? or am i missing something very obvious

Comment: How did you define the `client` before the code in answer?